# Finding the volume of a cylinder using a circle object

Tags: java, geometry, volume

I'm supposed to find the volume of a cylinder using a Circle object I made in another class. When I create my getVolume method, it tells me I can't multiply a Circle and double, and wanted to know how to fix it. I can't make a getArea method in the Cylinder class, just make a new Circle using a user-inputted radius. Here's the code (first for the Circle class, and second the Cylinder class):

```
public class Circle {
  private double radius;

  public Circle(double r) {
  radius = r;
  }

  public double getArea() {
      return Math.PI * radius * radius;
  }
}

public class Cylinder {
  private Circle base;
  private double height;

  public Cylinder(double r, double h) {
    base = new Circle(r);
    height = h;
  }

  public double getVolume() {
    return base * height;
  }
}
```

So the getVolume method is my problem. How can I get the program to recognize "base" as a double while it is still a Circle object?

Answer (score 3):

You wanted to write

```
 public double getVolume() {
   return base.getArea() * height;
  }
```

Right?

Otherwise, just by thinking of it: do you multiply a **circle** with a length? No, you multiply an **area** with a length to get the volume...

Also, if the circle would have a name attribute too, what should be multiplied? There is no magic, the JVM does what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply the area of the circle by the height.  But you can't multiply a `Circle` and a `double`.  Call `getArea()` on your `Circle`.

```
return base.getArea() * height;
```

Answer (score 1):

`return base.getArea() * height`